# React: How to pass props to child route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So these codes are generated from `.NetCore` with react template. So I have `App.js`:

```
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/home/Home';
import { FetchData } from './components/home/FetchData';
import { Counter } from './components/home/Counter';

import './custom.css'

export default class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;

  render () {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
        <Route path='/fetch-data' component={FetchData} />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

Which render the `Layout`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { NavMenu } from '../navigations/NavMenu';
import { Login } from './account/Login';

export class Layout extends Component {
    static displayName = Layout.name;

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Login />
                <NavMenu />
                <Container>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The `Layout` renders `Login`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Login.css';

export class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { show: false };
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.showLogin = this.showLogin.bind(this);
    }

    showLogin() {
        this.setState({
            show: true
        });
    }

    login() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className={this.state.show ? "login-form " : "login-form hide"} onSubmit={this.login()}>
                <h1>Login</h1>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input required type="text" placeholder="Email" />
                    <input required type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Then this is one of the child component `FetchData`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { http } from '../../helpers/Http';

export class FetchData extends Component {
    static displayName = FetchData.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { forecasts: [], loading: true };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.populateWeatherData();
    }

    async populateWeatherData() {
        const data = await http.getData(null, 'WeatherForecast');
        this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
    }

    static renderForecastsTable(forecasts) {
        return (
            <table className='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tabelLabel">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                        <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                        <th>Summary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {forecasts.map(forecast =>
                        <tr key={forecast.Date}>
                            <td>{forecast.Date}</td>
                            <td>{forecast.TemperatureC}</td>
                            <td>{forecast.TemperatureF}</td>
                            <td>{forecast.Summary}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : FetchData.renderForecastsTable(this.state.forecasts);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="tabelLabel" >Weather forecast</h1>
                <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
                {contents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to access `Login` from `FetchData` so whenever the user is not authorized, it calls `showLogin()` from `Login` component.

How do I do this?

Comment: React doesn't quite work this way. If more than one component needs to access the same state/function then that state/function needs to be moved to a common ancestor. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: So should I move `Login` into `App.js` instead of `Layout`? I still don't quite get about the `<Container> {this.props.children}</Container>` inside the `Layout`. Could you help me explain it?

Comment: I think for this a React Context may serve a better use-case. Store the auth state (and state updater) there and any component can access the context to check, or set, the auth state. Your `Login` component can then conditionally render the login form. It might be even better to render your login form/page/component on a "/login" route and then any component can do a direct to your login route to force a user to authenticate.